# .NET DI Internal Constructor and Console Logging

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, dependency-injection

I have the following classes in `ProjectA`:

```cs
public class ApplicationBuilder
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _services;
    
    internal ApplicationBuilder() => _services = new ServiceCollection();

    public ApplicationBuilder ConfigureServices(Action<IServiceCollection> services)
    {
        _services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
        _services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
        _services
            .AddLogging(builder => builder
                .AddConsole()
                .ClearProviders()
                .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information));
        
        _services.AddSingleton<Application>();

        services.Invoke(_services);
        
        return this;
    }
    
    public Application Build()
    {
        var provider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
        
        return provider.GetRequiredService<Application>();
    }
}

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection")]

public class Application
{
    private readonly ILogger<Application> _logger;
    internal Application(ILogger<Application> logger) => _logger = logger;
    
    public static ApplicationBuilder Create() => new();

    public void Run()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Application started");
        while (true)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

And the following in `ProjectB`:

```cs
Application.Create()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        
    })
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

I get the following exception:
`Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Application' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.`

I thought `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection")]` would allow DI to construct the type but apparently not. Is there some way to create my own constructor resolver that can use internal constructors?

Also if I skip this problem and make the constructor public (which I don't want to do), the logger doesn't log anything. Am I missing something with the setup for the logger?

Thanks

EDIT: Turns out AddLogging / ClearProviders() was the problem with the logger, I normally do this when using full .NET hosts to clear out the default framework messages but as they aren't here anyways it was clearing out the console logging provider.

Comment: MS.DI solely supports auto-wiring on *public* constructors. It doesn't invoke internal constructors, even if it *could*.  What problem are you solving by keeping that constructor internal? Is `Application` part of a reusable library where you don't control the consumers (e.g. is the library shipped as NuGet package)? In case the library is only used in a single solution, making a ctor internal typically has little use.

Comment: The `Application` is configured and created by the `ApplicationBuilder` (which can internally access the constructor) I don't want to provide public access to a constructor that requires injected services. I can get around this with `_services.AddSingleton(new Application(provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Application>>()))` but it's an anti pattern that I would rather avoid

Comment: Can you describe why you think that is an anti-pattern? I'm pretty familiar with DI and the patterns and practices surrounding it, and I don't see that as an anti-pattern.

Comment: Because you are manually handling the dependencies of an object used in DI where the container should be responsible for handling that for you.

Comment: I would certainly not consider this an anti-pattern, although, surely, you wouldn't want to use the lambda registration on a great part of your registrations. I'd say it's a good idea to lean on you're container's Auto-Wiring abilities for as much as you can; but don't hesitate to apply lambda registrations on places where it makes more sense.

Comment: Consider an object that needs to be scoped, without first scoping the object and then calling GetRequiredService on the scope, you are breaking the pattern. I just don't think it's a very clean approach and is best to avoid where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I saw your issue was different, but still, consider this a rewrite for how it can be done.

First of all, remember [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is from `System.Windows` namespace. So I wouldn't use it. Further below, I'll rewrite the code with some other name.

---

```cs
 internal Application(ILogger<Application> logger) => _logger = logger;
```

Why not removing the `internal` keyword as a whole alongside the code above? Let's try rewriting it in a way you don't need to do *crazy internal witchcraft.*

---

**A better approach**

**Interfaces:**

They can be set up in `Project B` or in a standalone `Abstractions` project shared by both `Project A` and `Project B`.

The following is an interface for configuring services (which returns the second interface when calling `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Configures the service application and returns the service built.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TApplication">Application Type</typeparam>
public interface IAppBuilderConfigureServices<TApplication>
    where TApplication: class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a service injection container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">Opts for configuring services.</param>
    /// <returns>App Service Builder</returns>
    IAppBuildService<TApplication> ConfigureServices(Action<IServiceCollection> services);
}
```

Interface for building the service:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Builds the configuration and gets <see cref="TApplication"/> from container.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TApplication">Application Type</typeparam>
public interface IAppBuildService<TApplication>
    where TApplication: class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// App Service builder that returns Singleton of <see cref="TApplication"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Instance of <see cref="TApplication"/></returns>
    TApplication Build();
}
```

**Project A:**

`internal` application builder:

```
/// <summary>
/// Internally builds the service application and returns the service built.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TApplication">Application Type</typeparam>
internal class AppBuilder<TApplication> : IAppBuilderConfigureServices<TApplication>, IAppBuildService<TApplication>
    where TApplication: class
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _services = new ServiceCollection();
    
    public IAppBuildService<TApplication> ConfigureServices(Action<IServiceCollection> services)
    {
        _services.AddLogging(s => s.ClearProviders().AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug));
        _services.AddSingleton<TApplication>();

        services.Invoke(_services);
        return this;
    }

    public TApplication Build() => _services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<TApplication>();
}

public static class AppBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of <see cref="IAppBuilderConfigureServices{TApplication}"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TApplication">Application Type</typeparam>
    /// <returns>Application builder</returns>
    public static IAppBuilderConfigureServices<TApplication> Create<TApplication>()
        where TApplication : class =>
        new AppBuilder<TApplication>();
}
```

**Project B:**

Just of an example of how it `MyApp` can be configured.

```cs
public static class ProjectB
{
    public static MyApp Initialize()
    {
        return AppBuilder.Create<MyApp>()
            .ConfigureServices(config =>
            {
                // ...
            })
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Finally, your application code:

```cs
public class MyApp
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyApp> _logger;

    public MyApp(ILogger<MyApp> logger) => _logger = logger;

    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

This is a draft but I think you get the idea. I'm using interfaces to make it more readable, sorry about the summaries, as I wanted to demonstrate what things were going to do.

---

Usage:

```cs
ProjectB.Initialize().HelloWorld();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had considered pulling out some interfaces into a separate projects to get past the issue but it seemed a bit overkill considering this is the only publicly exposed class that requires DI. I ended up just using some reflection to get the constructor and invoke it inside AddSingleton:

`var constructor = typeof(Application).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).First();
services.AddSingleton((Application)constructor.Invoke(constructor.GetParameters().Select(p => provider.GetRequiredService(p.ParameterType)).ToArray()));`

Comment: @ScottKane you don't need them in a separate project, it's optional (and not really needed for your use-case). Your way seems much more antisharp than it should...